# Question in analysis: subset of open interval in $\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces

> Consider metric space $(X,d)$, $X=(a,b)\subset \Bbb R$, $d(x,y)= \lvert x-y \rvert$. Let a subset $S \subset (a,b)$ be open and closed. Show that either $S=(a,b)$ or $S= \emptyset$.

There's a hint given:
Assume $S \ne \emptyset$ so there is a point $x_0 \in S$. Define set
$$T_1 = \{ x \vert\ \exists\ x<x_0\text{ s.t. }(x,x_0 ] \subset S \}$$
and
$$T_2 = \{ y \vert\ \exists\ y>x_0\text{ s.t. }[x_0,y) \subset S \}.$$
Show $T_1, T_2 \ne \emptyset$ and $\inf T_1=a, \sup T_2=b$

I did something that didn't really use the hint. So suppose that $S \ne \emptyset$.
Clearly, $S$ cannot be just one point or any collection of isolated points since it wouldn't be open.
So $S$ must be some open interval $(x,y) \subset (a,b), x \le y$. Suppose $x \ne a$ and $y \ne b$.
The complement of $S$ in $X$, $S^c = (a,x] \cup [y,b)$, but this is not open so $S$ can't be closed. Hence, $S=(a,b)$.

Is this a valid argument or can someone see any mistakes that I've made? thanks

Comment: Non open subsets of $(a,b)$ can be different from sets consisting of isolated points.

Comment: Not every subset of an interval is an interval or a collection of isolated points; think of the set of rational numbers, or a Cantor-type set. Trying to proceed using any type of "classification" is hopeless. :)

Comment: "So S must be some open interval (x,y)⊂(a,b)" is not a right deny to "just one point or any collection of isolated points"

Comment: Thanks for the comments. So using the hint: Suppose $infT_1 \ne a$, then by definition of $T_1$, $(a, infT_1]$ lies outside of $S$ so $(a, infT_1] \subset S^c$. This means that $S^c$ can't be open since there's no finite ball such that $B(infT_1,r) \subset S^c$ so $S$ is not closed. Hence, $infT_1 = a$. And similarly for the other side with $T_2$. Comment/criticism?

Comment: @Alex If $T_1=\emptyset$, then $\inf T_1=\infty$, so $(a,\inf T_1)$ is not contained in the complement of $S$.

Comment: @Alex $\inf T_1$ could even be in $S$, so $(a,\inf T_1]$ may not be a subset of $S^C$.

Comment: @AlexR could you explain why $infT_1$ could be in $S$? I realised a mistake I made in my earlier post: it doesn't follow that $(a, infT_1)$ lies outside of $S$ since this interval may contain elements of $S$ that are nonetheless not in $(infT_1, x_0)$...can someone give me any additional direction, I'm slightly lost in this...

Comment: @Alex Imagine $S = [x_1, x_0]$ i.e. $S$ to have a left endpoint. Then $\inf T_1 = x_1 \in S$. Note that this is no valid $S$ (since the only valid $S$ are $\emptyset$ and $(a,b)$), but it illustrates the problem. You can't assume that $\inf T_1\notin S$ unless you prove it.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is incorrect. There are many more non open subsets of $(a,b)$, besides sets of isolated points.

You're basically assuming the thesis to prove it, because intervals are indeed the only connected subsets of $(a,b)$ (or, more generally, of $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've added a further attempt in the comment section. Could you let me know if I'm any closer?